# Linearity of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Ordinals are defined as a set which is transitive and all its elements are transitive.

In the proof of linearity of ordinals i.e. $$\forall a \forall b : a<b  \vee a>b \vee a=b $$
We assume that this fails and choose minimal $a$ such that $b$ is neither less than or greater than or equal to $a$. How do we know we can choose such a minimal element? i.e.
1) How do we know the set of such $a$ has all elements comparable  (aren't we proving this very thing ?)?
2) If this set has all elements comparable then how is a minimal element guaranteed?

One can go further and ask does 1) makes sense, i.e. do such $a$s make a set. How does one answer this question?

Comment: Note that in general, a minimal element doesn't imply a minimum. A minimal element of a set is just an element for which there is no smaller element in the set. In particular, an element that is incomparable with any other element in the set is automatically minimal. Note also that a set may have more than one minimal element.

Comment: So we don't need every element to be comparable still it leaves the second question unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different proof. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be ordinals. If $\alpha = \beta$, then there is nothing do to. So, suppose wlog that $\beta \not \subseteq \alpha$. Let $\gamma = \min_{\in} \beta \setminus \alpha$. (Such a minimum exists by regularity and the transitivity of $\beta$.)

Now show that $\gamma = \alpha$ (using extensionality) and hence $\alpha \in \beta$.